# How to set/get a field of a nested composite type variable?

Tags: postgresql, composite-types

For example:

```
create type t1 as (a int2, b text, c boolean);
create type t2 as (a t1, b boolean);
create type t3 as (a t2, b int4);
```

Now, how can I do the following for a variable x of type t3:

```
x.a.a.c := true;
y := x.a.a.c;
```

The first gives me an error.

Comment: Good question. For a *one* level composite, it's straightforward: `x.a := z.a ;` would work. It doesn't when you're some levels deeper... *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fec6f34b6963b04807f47cb5a5ab7556)*. I thought this [Accessing Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING) would help, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

There's one (*awful*, in my opinion) **workaround**... you can access only one level down at a time. Use intermediate variables.

```
DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
$$
DECLARE 
    x t3 ;
    x2 t2 ;
    x1 t1 ;
BEGIN
    -- x.a.a.c := true;   -- Syntax error

    x2 := x.a ;
    x1 := x2.a ;
    x1.c := true ;
    x2.a := x1 ;
    x.a := x2 ;
END ;
$$
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=cee1a11efc691d24f9a1d6e534cc54f7)*

Answer (score 3):

You can assign the row type as a whole, which does what you ask for. But it also overwrites every other (sub-)field. (I use NULL for the rest.) See `x` in the demo.

You can also assign a whole composite type value to a column at the outer level. This preserves all other column values in the outer level. See `y` in the demo.

But you cannot do the same for nested composite types. See `z` in the demo.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
   x t3;
   y t3;
   z t3;
BEGIN
   x      := '("(""(,,true)"",)",)'::t3;  -- works
   y.a    :=    '("(,,true)",)'::t2;      -- works
--(z.a).a :=      '(,,true)'::t1;         -- does not work
   RAISE NOTICE E'\nx: %\ny: %\nz: %', x, y, z;
END
$$
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d5f0bf7bea37e5246c5f274736add836)*
(Using an `EXCEPTION` to make the result visible in the fiddle.)